# How to do the Kolmogorov Smirnov Test for generalized Hyperbolic Distribution in R?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov

I want to do the Kolmogor Smirnov test for the generalized hyperbolic distribution. I use data about stocks and the package "ghyp".
The code that I am using is

Theta3 <- ghyp(lambda=-0.68, alpha.bar=0.36, mu=0.00003, sigma=-0.0084,gamma=0.02)
ks.test(data1$MSFT, "pghyp", Theta3)

but i get the following message:
Error in ghypCheckPars(param) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Could you please help me?